# What is a simplest, low-profile, yet modern solution to host a small web service in a .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, client-server

I'm developing a windows web service in .net which does some work on a server periodically in the background.
I also need a very simple interface with one method with a small amount of parameters that can be called by client applications. This needs to be hosted in the web service.
What is the most low profile yet modern approach to do this?
My guess would be a self-hosted WCF service library.
Is there anything simpler when you only need such a minimal API?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into Web API. https://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Is this for testing?  Can't you just create a simple Console application to host your services?